# How to get an associated language version of a menu item by modifying the URL in Joomla?

Tags: translation, non-sef-url

I have a page

https://example.com/terms-and-conditions

in my Joomla, which has the same page also in other languages, properly associated and translated, along with menu items (English has the menu item ID 281)

Is there a way to get the translated version of the other pages just by adding a language parameter to the URL?

For example for the German version (which lives under https://example.com/agb) I
have tried the following:

https://example.com/de/terms-and-conditions (does not work)

or (by menu item ID)

https://example.com/?Itemid=281&lang=de (does not work)
and

https://example.com/de/?Itemid=281 (does not work)

Is there any way to do this?
This would come in handy for automation or links that would need to be translated in content.

Or would I have to write my own URL router for this kind of URL?